# How to specify the subscription and resource manager for private Endpoint in ARM template different from default

Tags: azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

In ARM template , how do we specify the subscription and resource group where private endpoint is located if it is different from default subscription where template is running.

Comment: you explain a little bit more please ?add some details, the arm template you are working on ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `resourceId` function to retrieve and specify the required values. this Works irrespective of where the templet is running
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid

Comment: "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",I am not finding an  option to specify subscription ID/Resource Group ID with private end point